# Correlation function in matlab

Tags: matlab, correlation

I am using the correlation function in matlab. My code is about finding the peak to side lobe ratio. 
     But the problem is corr function works slow for images.Is there any other alternative for this function and any better method to calculate peak to sidelobe ratio.
     I am finding some problems here in uploading the code but can mail anyone for the reference.

Comment: The peak-to-sidelobe ratio of what?

Comment: Perhaps copying and pasting an example of what you're trying to do would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matlab correlation function works efficiently for what it is intended for. If it is choking point, you could try the following, courtesy of the [Matlab Forms](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/4029-find-the-sidelobe-level).

1. Use the findpeak() function to find the two highest peaks.
2. Take the first peak divided by the second peak, and you have a Peak to Sidelobe ratio.

Alternatively, you could use the diff function to find the point where the slope changes, helping to identify the peak, and then use step 2.